# Replace variable by value in gap

Tags: gap

I want to generate a list of maps in a function and return this list. For example the list of maps 
  $$ [k\mapsto k+1,\ k\mapsto k+2,\ k\mapsto k+3] $$
I thought I could do this by the following code:

```
get_maps := function()
   local maps,i;
   maps := [];
   for i in [1..3] do
      Add(maps,k->k+i);
   od;
   return maps;
end;
```

But the value of `i` changes inside the function. So in fact I get three identical mappings $k\mapsto k+3$.

How can I access the value of `i` inside the function instead of the variable `i`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens here is that when the list of `k->k+1` maps is returned, it takes the current value of `i` (local variable defined in `get_maps`) which is 3 after the `for` loop has been completed.

You can avoid this by placing the function creation within a function (in the example called `construct_map`: Then the `i` added is always the local variable `i`, which for each iteration of the function will be a different variable, assigned to a different value.

Try the following:

```
get_maps := function()
   local maps, i, construct_map;
   maps := [];
   construct_map := i -> (k -> k+i);
   for i in [1..3] do
      Add( maps, construct_map(i) );
   od;
   return maps;
end;
```

Then it works as desired:

```
gap> f:=get_maps();
[ function( k ) ... end, function( k ) ... end, function( k ) ... end ]
gap> List(f, t -> t(1));
[ 2, 3, 4 ]
```

However all three functions with `Print` as `k->k+i`, wirth the value of `i` hidden. If you really want the functions to be (e.g.) `k->k+3`, you would have to produce a string with the function definition (including the concrete number) and evaluate it.

Comment: Thanks @ahulpke for the improvement!

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed. Just for the sake of completeness: I think your local `map` should be `construct_map`

Comment: @Thorsten thanks - fixed the name!